Downgrade/reinstall GStreamer launch and core library
I'm working with a project that seems to require GStreamer ~1.16.2 to run (I know for a fact it doesn't run on version 1.20). The system I have to work with is an Ubuntu 22.04, which comes with GStreamer 1.20.3 installed.
So far I've managed to remove, build and install version 1.16.2 following the instructions from https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/10.0/multimedia/gstreamer10.html. However, when I check the version, this is what I get:
$ gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.16.2
GStreamer 1.20.3
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/

and
$ gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version
GStreamer Core Library version 1.20.3

I tried running the project and it has the same issue as if I didn't change anything (the case in which both gst-launch-1.0 and the core library were at 1.20.3). If I understand it correctly, I changed the binaries, but the libs are still the same. Which begs the question: how do I downgrade the libraries for the version I need?
